# How to use Cmder in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmder

At work, there is an enterprise security policy where all executables are only allowed to run out of `C:\Program Files` or `C:\Program Files (x86)`.

In Visual Studio Code, in `settings.json`, using the following settings:

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
        "/k C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Cmder\\vendor\\init.bat"
    ]
}
```

...on initialization for the integrated terminal, I receive the following error message:

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file.
```

Because of Windows' awesome file/directory naming convention allowing spaces, it is difficult to point to one of the `Program File` paths.

VSCode doesn't like it when you escape the space character, and this code gives me the error `Invalid escape character in string`. When I try to change the property to this:

```
{
    ...
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
        "/k C:\\Program\ Files\ (x86)\\Cmder\\vendor\\init.bat"
    ]
}
```

...I get the following error message:

```
'C:\ProgramFiles' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Lastly, trying to surround the path in quotes like this:

```
{
    ...
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
        "/k \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Cmder\\vendor\\init.bat\""
    ]
}
```

...gives me this error message:

```
'\"C:\Program Files (x86)\Cmder\vendor\init.bat\""' is not recognized as an 
internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Is there any way to integrate Cmder in VSCode?

Comment: Fix here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47267852/vscode-cmder-integration-strange-issue/48104881?noredirect=1#comment83209354_48104881

Comment: @Adson, thanks? I've already posted a solution to my question, and the answer you linked didn't exist until 5 months after I asked my question.

Comment: Surrounding the whole path in quotes is close to but not quite the correct syntax for it. The qoutation marks should surround the specific block of text containing spaces, i.e `"C:\\\"Program Files (x86)\"\\Cmder\\vendor\\init.bat"`. I know the issue is already resolved in other ways but I hope this tidbit is useful regardless.

Comment: **The official Cmder guide here:** https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/wiki/Seamless-VS-Code-Integration

Answer (score 75, accepted):

After scouring the Internet for answers, I couldn't find a solution, but I figured it out and thought I might post it here for others to see, as I've seen that people from different forums had the same question but there was no answer.

In Windows, there is a `/X` for the `dir` command, which states:

```
  /X          This displays the short names generated for non-8dot3 file
              names.  The format is that of /N with the short name inserted
              before the long name. If no short name is present, blanks are
              displayed in its place.
```

So, doing a `dir /X` command on `C:\` displays the following:

```
C:\>dir /X
 Volume in drive C is OSDisk
 Volume Serial Number is XXXX-XXXX

 Directory of C:\

...
08/17/2017  08:02 PM    <DIR>          PROGRA~1     Program Files
08/09/2017  03:58 PM    <DIR>          PROGRA~2     Program Files (x86)
...
```

You can use the directory short name `PROGRA~2` to substitute `Program Files (x86)`, and have the following settings in your `settings.json` for VS Code:

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
        "/k C:\\PROGRA~2\\Cmder\\vendor\\init.bat"
    ]
}
```

Which does load Cmder successfully in the integrated terminal:

[image: Image of Cmder being successfully loaded in the VS Code integrated terminal.]

Comment: how are you getting the colors and look in general of cmder in vscode? I follow your step and I did got cmder to work in the console but it is all white

Comment: @David Martinez, try changing the color scheme to a darker one. See this article: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes

Comment: if you guys cannot find C:/Windows/Sysnative folder try this: `C:\\WINDOWS\\SysWOW64\\cmd.exe`

Comment: There is an official documentation about Cmder integration in VS Code: https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/wiki/Seamless-VS-Code-Integration

Answer (score 24):

another solution is you can set your cmder location into new path

[image: image was from nikrolls when giving the solution]

and just set in your settings.json

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe",
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
    "/k %CMDER_ROOT%\\vendor\\init.bat"
]
```

you can find it on [cmder github issue](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/282)

Comment: There are also some _other_ benefits as well to set the environment variable: [github.com/cmderdev/cmder/wiki/Setting-up-Environment-Variables#should-i-use-this-method](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/wiki/Setting-up-Environment-Variables#should-i-use-this-method)

Answer (score 20):

This is the new method to do that '2021'

related to [this article](https://dev.to/andrewriveradev/how-to-setup-cmder-in-vscode-in-2021-3nkc)

Step 1: [Download Cmder](https://cmder.net/).

Step 2: Save Cmder to C:\ drive

Step 3: Open Settings.json in VSCode (File - Preferences - Settings ...)

Step 4: Enter this parameters:

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "Cmder": {
      "path": "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe",
      "args": ["/k", "C:\\cmder\\vendor\\bin\\vscode_init.cmd"]
    }
  },
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Cmder",
```

Comment: Works fine, but is there any way to remove the initial logging when opening a new terminal?

Comment: @g-otn You can update `%CMDER_ROOT%/bin/vscode_init_args.cmd` and comment the last few lines

Comment: Worked for me in 2022. Remember to replace C:\\ with whatever your actual path to cmdr is if its not in the root directory.

Answer (score 11):

#### Another approach.

The Cmder team suggests prepending a `^` character before each space in your path, instead of using the 8dot3 naming approach.

**Example:**

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
        "/k C:\\Program Files^ (x86)\\Cmder\\vendor\\init.bat"
    ]
}
```

#### Taken from [official Cmder wiki](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/wiki/Seamless-VS-Code-Integration):

> #### Spaces in path
>
> ⚠ **CAUTION:** The command line interpreter in Windows has some issues with *spaces in the path*, such as `C:\Program Files (x86)\Cmder`. We do *not recommended* to install Cmder in a path that contains spaces.
>
> Instead, we recommend installing Cmder in a path that does not contain any spaces, such as: `C:\apps\Cmder` or `C:\tools\Cmder` to avoid any conflicts with VS Code.
>
> If you for some reason really need to launch Cmder from a path with spaces, you might need to prepend a `^` symbol before each space, such that `C:\\Example Directory for Test\\Cmder` will become `C:\\Example^ Directory^ for^ Test\\Cmder` in your `settings.json` file.

Comment: According to my experiences, you have to escape the parentheses as well as spaces. Here's how `C:\Program Files (x86)\Cmder` works for me: `"C:\\Program^ Files^ ^(x86^)\\Cmder"`.

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/wiki/Seamless-VS-Code-Integration

```
 "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "cmd.exe",

  "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
  "CMDER_ROOT": "[cmder_root]"
  },
  "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
    "/k [cmder_root]\\vendor\\init.bat"
  ],
```

Substitute both [cmder_root] with your Cmder installation directory.

second solution

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\cmder\\vendor\\git-for-windows\\bin\\bash.exe",
```

Answer (score 3):

A very easy solution ([source](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/12006#issuecomment-315539390)):

Create a file in the root of your cmder folder `vscode.bat` with the following code.

```
@echo off
SET CMDER_ROOT=C:\cmder <--your path to cmder
"%CMDER_ROOT%\vendor\init.bat"
```

Then in your vscode settings add the following to your `settings.json`:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\sysnative\\cmd.exe",
 "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["/K", "C:\\cmder\\vscode.bat"] <-- your path
```

You can also easily switch between `cmd` and `cmder` by commenting in and out `"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows"`.

Answer (score 3):

Cmder with VSCode 2021

- Step 1: Download Cmder
- Step 2: Save Cmder to C:\cmder
- Step 3: Open Settings.json in VSCode
- Step 4: Create VSCode Integrated Terminal Settings

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "Cmder": {
      "path": "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe",
      "args": ["/k", "C:\\cmder\\vendor\\bin\\vscode_init.cmd"]
    }
  },
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Cmder",
```

- Step 5: restart VSCode
- Step 6: Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

It's work for me. My Cmder root directory: `D:\soft\cmder`, attention yours!

```
"terminal.integrated.env.windows": {"CMDER_ROOT": "D:\\soft\\cmder"},
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["/k D:\\soft\\cmder\\vendor\\init.bat"],
```

Add it in your VSCode settings. enjoy it!

Comment: The previous solutions did not work for me, with an error message in the terminal about not being able to access "C:\Config". This solution, however, did work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found:
Fast and easy.

```
"terminal.external.windowsExec": "C:\\Utils\\Cmder\\Cmder.exe",
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\sysnative\\cmd.exe"
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows" : ["/K","C:\\Utils\\cmder\\vendor\\init.bat"],
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution its good on open terminal but breaks cmd calls launched via plugins with arguments like npm build - lint, etc.

A solution to fix it is to create a custom init.bat that wraps these calls and reference it on sellArgs.

> settings.json

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "cmd.exe",
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
    "/K C:\\SoftDev\\App\\Cmder\\vendor\\vstudio.bat"
],
```

> C:\SoftDev\App\cmder\vendor\vstudio.bat

```
@echo off
if "%1" == "" (
    C:\SoftDev\App\cmder\vendor\init.bat
) else (
    cmd %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
    exit
)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Ari Maulana works like a charm...

add "CMDER_ROOT" on variables and just set in your settings.json

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe",
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
    "/k %CMDER_ROOT%\\vendor\\init.bat"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two Extensions to include Cmder into VS Code but none of them work in Win 7 (I know is quite old) anyway while some of the answer here helped didn't work for my case.

The locations details:

```
cmd.exe = C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
I am using a portable version of Cmder in C:\cmder\Cmder.exe
init.bat = C:\cmder\vendor\init.bat
setting.json = C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json
```

This is my settings.json

```
{
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
        "/k C:\\cmder\\vendor\\init.bat"
    ]
}
```

And the screenshot where it's properly working

[Cmder integrated into VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZ0uY.png)

Note: That I didn't need to add Cmder into the Environment Path

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio press `ctrl` + `p`

Write / go to `settings.json`

Paste this inside

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
  "Cmder": {
    "path": "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe",
    "args": ["/k", "C:\\cmder\\vendor\\git-for-windows\\bin\\bash.exe"]
  }
},
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Cmder",
```

Make sure that the `"args"` is the directory where you placed cmder in your machine.

Answer (score -1):

The command line interpreter in Windows has some issues with spaces in the path, such as C:\Program Files\Cmder or C:\Program Files (x86)\Cmder. instead, create a new folder like "apps" and use path has no space like c:\apps